# Right way to redirect to list page after successful add

Tags: symfony1

Simple question I'm sure but in Symfony 1.4. After I the form is submitted to add what is the best way to automatically go to the list all page?

Comment: Are you talking about admin generated modules or a custom one?

Comment: I created a custom module. I'm having issues redirecting after the add form is submitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typical symfony setting, the general idea would be:

```
public function executeCreate($request) {
  $form = new FooForm();
  if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
    $form->bind((array) $request->getParameter('foo'));
    if ($form->isValid()) {
      $form->save();
      $this->redirect('@route_name_for_list');
    }
  }
  $this->form = $form;
}
```

Comment: thanks, what is the last executable line doing? $this->form = $form;

Comment: It passes the $form variable to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have found the name of the route that leads to the list all page, let's call it stuff_index, you can simply do this: `$this->redirect('@stuff_index');`

Comment: why use the '@' symbol before it?

Comment: The code of redirect says you should use the `url_for` format, but the code in `convertUrlStringToParameter` seems to show the @ is actually optional if you don't provide any parameters throught a query string.

Comment: It is indeed optional but better practice, and a way to better distinguish actual route names with other possible formats of the parameter to the redirect function, like an actual URL or a 'module/action' pair.

Comment: Note that the '@' is useful when you use the `url_for()` helper. When you use it, url_for will expect parameters as a query string, and when you don't, as an associative array.